# TIMEDIFF FUNCTION doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

[Query Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwUXr.png)

From the Output, you can see that I can select the `MIN(TIME(Time))` but when I use it in `TIMEDIFF FUNCTION` it reads the `MIN(TIME(Time))` as 0 and I get a result of -07:00:00. I want to get the difference of `MIN(TIME(Time))` and 07:00:00 for me to determine the number of hours an employee is late. Any suggestions on how to fix this? All responses are much appreciated. Sorry for the bad english.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","september-system");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT User_ID, MIN(TIME(Time)) as time, DATE(Time) as day, TIMEDIFF('MIN(TIME(Time))', '07:00:00')as tdiff  FROM records GROUP BY User_ID, day ORDER BY User_ID, day;";



if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
{
do
{
// Store first result set
if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con)) {
  echo "<table><tr><th>USER ID</th><th>TIME</th><th>DATE</th><th>ABSENCES</th></tr>";
 // output data of each row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    //echo var_dump($row);
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0]. "</td><td>" . $row[1]. "</td><td>" . $row[2]. "</td><td>" . $row[3]. "</td></tr>";
    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
}
while(mysqli_more_results($con) && mysqli_next_result($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I didn't check but I can say take the variable first and then make the different between them.

Comment: @Virb How can I do that? I'm really sorry I'm new to php and all I've been doing is searching the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to remove the single quote from the first parameter
lets try , i'm not sure

```
 TIMEDIFF(MIN(TIME(Time)), '07:00:00')as tdiff
```